# forecasting with panel data

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting, multivariate-analysis, panel-data

I have a panel data where each unit is a store that has sales information of 2 years at a weekly interval. I want to forecast sales at a store level. How should I approach in MULTIVARITE construct. I have used VAR model on time series data but not on panel data. Is there any way out using python.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: can we forecast using VAR models when we have panel data? If yes, how do we implement it in python?